# How to translate vb code into php code

Tags: cakephp, vbscript

I am unable to translate this below written VB script code into php code so please help me in providing with the php code by translating the given VB code.

**VBScript Sample:**

```
Dim HttpObj
Dim sURL
Dim sPage
Dim strResult

sURL = "http://example.com"
Set HTTPObj = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
HTTPObj.open "get", sURL, False
HTTPObj.Send
sPage = HTTPObj.responseText
```

Comment: Please check your code, it looks as if though some of it is missing or has been cut off somehow (the lines seem cut-off).

Comment: how to create object of ServerXMLHTTP and MSXML parser in php

Comment: You can use the "edit" link just below your initial question to update the question itself.

Comment: Boil it down to *what does this code do*, then look for an answer. You want to know how to download a remote XML file and parse it in PHP, not how to use ServerXMLHTTP and MSXML.

Comment: Yes i am looking forward to download an remote XML file and then will parse it in php...

Comment: I am looking for its code in php..

Comment: Have you tried looking for a solution to that problem? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+parse+xml

Answer (score 0):

Based on the broken code you have pasted it would seem you want to fetch a xml page and convert into a usable array.

The book contains just that, as an example [twitter api](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1077/An-Example)

Line 46 does your `HttpObj`

Line 61 gets the data and converts to array. You can use the [Xml libs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1486/Xml-parsing) instead.

I have posted some 1.3 links, but it should be the same for 2.x. I just could not find the twitter example in the 2.x examples.